# Rails 4 has_many though where filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to group/filter/select by a records' attribute though a join table. While I understand there are other ways of achieving the same result (one of which I use below) I was wondering if the same could be achieved with a HMT relation.

The models are as follows:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :bars, through: foo_bars

  # SOMETHING LIKE THIS:
  has_many :group_a_bars, -> where { foo_bars.bar.bar_group_id: 1 }
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: bars
  # bar_group_id :integer          not null

  belongs_to :bar_group
end

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end

class BarGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end
```

What I would like to be able to do in the view is something like: `#{foo.group_a_bars}` which would all of the `FooBars` that have `bars` that belong to the first `bar_group`

The same could be accomplished with something like:

```
foo.foo_bars.find_all{ |foo_bar| foo_bar.bar.bar_group_id == 1 }
```

**EDIT:** Following the advice of @smathy I added a join and got it working with the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :bars, through: foo_bars

  # WORKING:
  has_many    :group_a_bars,
                ->              { joins(:bar).where(bars: { bar_group_id: 1 }) },
                class_name:     "FooBar",
                source:         :bar
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it'll be something like this:

```
has_many :group_a_bars,
  -> { joins(:bar).where( bar: { bar_group_id: 1 } ) }, through: :foo_bars, class_name: "Bar"
```

You might need a `:source` option in there too.